# Submitting Html Form with Python's Mechanize - two submit buttons no IDs

Tags: mechanize-python

I am trying to submit a HTML button on a PHP/HTML page that contains 1 form and two different buttons that do different tasks. I need to submit the second submit button. The problem is that neither button has an id attribute and are distinguished only by their title tag. 
I need to select Orders and Orderlines via a select box (which I think is correct) and press the second 'Go'/Submit button on the form.
e.g.

```
<form>
....
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Go">
....
```

then further down we have...

```
<select class="sfield" name="last">
    <option value="0" selected="">From: First order</option>
    <option value="1">From: 19/10/2012 16:22</option>
</select>
<select class="sfield" name="items">
    <option value="1" selected="">Include: Orders and items</option>
    <option value="0">Include: Order lines only</option>
</select>
<input class="button" type="submit" onclick="this.form.action.value='export'" title="Generate CSV file" value="Go">
```

My Python code snippet is as follows...

```
br.form['last']  = ['0']  # Select the 'From First Order'
br.form['items'] = ['1']  # Select both Orders and Order Lines
br.submit()

# When I uncomment the line below I can process a CSV file but it just contains Orders only!
# br.open("http://www.mysite.com/admin/ordermanager.php?action=export")  

# Read and process CSV file from csv link displayed on repost of submitted form....
# this section below works fine.

for link in br.links(url_regex=r"export",nr=0):
    resp = br.follow_link(link) 
    content = resp.read()
    Last_Run_Date = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime())
    with open('c:\python27\%s.csv' % Last_Run_Date, 'w') as fo: 
        fo.write(content)
```

There does not seem to be a way of specifying the title attribute in the br.submit such as
    br.submit(title='Generate CSV file') in the Mechanize documentation.
I am assuming that br.submit() is selecting the first submit control when I want the second?
Does anyone know of a clever way around this?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the number of the submit button:
br.submit(nr=2)
nr starts from 0 for the first submit button